# C# travis build fails because nuget packages cannot be found

Tags: nuget, travis-ci

I am having trouble running a build on travis. On our local jenkins machine everything is fine. The travis build fails with the following state

```
Unable to find version '4.8.0.770-beta' of package 'Lucene.Net'.
```

The solution folder contains a nuget.config file that specifies multiple nuget feeds. My guess is that something is going wrong there. I could use some help.

The project is on GitHub at https://github.com/RHEAGROUP/docupanel

Comment: by the way, the travis yml file is on the development branch

Comment: Did you solve it? Is it the same issue as [this one](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4907)?